# MySQL join statement returns only one joint record

Tags: mysql, join

I have to two tables:

request:

```
+----+------+----+
| id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
|  1 | aaaa | aa |
+----+------+----+
|  2 | aaab | ab |
+----+------+----+
|  3 | aabb | bb |
+----+------+----+
```

request_status

```
+----+--------+---------+---------+
| id | req_id |  status |  time   |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    1   | pending |  mm-dd  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  2 |    1   | sent    |  mm-dd  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  3 |    2   | pending |  mm-dd  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  2 |    2   | failed  |  mm-dd  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
|  4 |    3   | pending |  mm-dd  |
+----+--------+---------+---------+
```

On request table i have can have to records: for intermediate status and completed request status.

What I need is some kind of join statement, that returns only one status per request, but returns pending status only if failed or sent does not exist.

Result:

```
+----+------+----+---------+
| id | from | to | status  |
+----+------+----+---------+
|  1 | aaaa | aa | sent    |
+----+------+----+---------+
|  2 | aaab | ab | failed  |
+----+------+----+---------+
|  3 | aabb | bb | pending |
+----+------+----+---------+

select r.id, r.from, r.to, s.status  from requests r
join request_status s on r.id = s.req_status
where r.status not like 'pending'
```

Will return without pending status.

Comment: The data and query is incorrect. Have you tested the query you have posted? It will be better to provide DDL and DML statements for the above data and post query which is tested.

Comment: There are possibilities, but how is your logic working, are there rules that are applied, that whenever a request is sent , there is no way anymore data is inserted with that request_id?

Comment: and why are your request_status id's not unique?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to display each row of `request` joined to the *most recent* corresponding row in `request_status`.

For this to work reasonably well, your `request_status.id` column needs to be a primary key and needs to be autoincrementing. That is, each new row in `request_status` must have a higher value of `id`. That's how we tell which row is more recent than another.

Then, it's easy.  This subquery yields the set of `id` values that are most recent. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c845b/1/0)

```
        SELECT MAX(id) latest_id
          FROM request_status
         GROUP BY req_id
```

You then use the subquery in the join as follows (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c845b/3/0)

```
SELECT r.id, r.from, r.to, s.status
  FROM request r
  JOIN request_status s ON r.id = s.req_id
  JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(id) latest_id
              FROM request_status
             GROUP BY req_id
        ) t ON s.id = t.latest_id
```

The third JOIN operation is basically equivalent to

```
 WHERE s.id IN (
        SELECT MAX(id) latest_id
          FROM request_status
         GROUP BY req_id
       )
```

It filters out all but the latest status row for each request id.